# Batch file to run exe with unknown filename as arguments

Tags: batch-file

I have an exe for comparing 2 .csv files. And it works when I open cmd window, drag exe, type space, drag 1st csv file, type space, and drag 2nd file.

Now I want to automate it, and the problem is it is never on the same place, nor uses the same files for comparing...

What I got so far is following in batch:

`%~dp0\Komparator.exe BC101.csv BC102.csv 
pause`

those 2 csv files are going to be in same folder, next to .exe and .bat file... but that "same folder" is not always the same, today its one location, another day is another folder

but I dont know how to automate those 2 arguments for file names, I just want it to recognize two .csv files near .exe and .bat

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the two CSV files in the same folder?  Are they only ever in one sub-folder?  Basically what I am saying is will they only ever be found once within a directory structure.

Comment: @Squashman yes, those 2 csv files are going to be in same folder, next to .exe and .bat file... but that "same folder" is not always the same, today its one location, another day is another folder

Comment: Then I don't understand what your predicament is.  Select both CSV files with your mouse and drag and drop them onto the batch file.  Then your batch file code becomes: `%~dp0\Komparator.exe %1 %2`

Comment: Just put `%~dp0\` in front of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read csv filenames and store them into batch variables using `for` cycle.
Here's an example, assuming your csv files are in the same directory as the batch file.

**compare.cmd**

```
@echo off
set FILE1=
set FILE2=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b %~dp0*.csv 2^>nul ^| sort') do (
    if defined FILE1 set "FILE2=%%~a" & goto :exit_loop
    set "FILE1=%%~a"
) 
:exit_loop
if not defined FILE1 echo first csv file not found!& goto :eof
if not defined FILE2 echo second csv file not found!& goto :eof
%~dp0\Komparator.exe "%~dp0%FILE1%" "%~dp0%FILE2%"
```

Comment: Working! Thank you for helping me and not criticizing me for asking for a code.

Comment: I'm glad to help.

Comment: Seems complicated when a simple `%~dp0\` prefix on the file names would have sufficed.

Comment: What is the purpose of the sort?

Comment: @wolfrevokcats, I would like you to test that theory with files named t0.csv to t11.csv.

Comment: @Squashman, if need be we can put whatever numerical sort tool in place of `sort`

Comment: @jwdonahue OP asked to *recognize* csv files near the .bat

Comment: @wolfrevokcats, sure, if your company allows that.

Comment: @wolfrevokcats Current solution with sort is working 100%,I havent mention but my comparator is showing info like "Present in file 1 AND Missing in file 2: (DATA HERE), Missing in file 1 AND Present in file 2: (DATA HERE)" and since files are listed in alphabetical order in windows explorere view, it is very good that I have sorting in batch command, to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Orion310591, I don't think you are understanding the problem.  Your files will only sort in the correct order if they start with the same amount of alpha characters and have the same amount of numbers in the file names for each file.  So if you were comparing BC99.csv with BC100.csv, the BC100.csv file would be first.

Comment: Ok, I got it now, this is how I will solve it  `%~dp0\Komparator.exe "%FILE1%" "%FILE2%"  
ECHO FILE 1 IS %FILE1%  ECHO FILE 2 IS %FILE2%
pause`

Comment: @wolfrevokcats, 26 years in the industry doing data automation. Details are crucial to what I do.

Comment: But details about ordering are simply not there. When we define the precise order then we fix the sorting as necessary. Currently it is not known if order is at all important.

Comment: @wolfrevokcats, wasn't me.  Your code is solid other than me knit picking over the sort. I'll give you an up vote.